# is there an url for photo gallery so that we could jump to in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, gallery, photo

I want user jump to their photo gallery after pressing a button.

Is there a URL for that? I am using objective-c if it matters.

Comment: I think there is no way for this.

Comment: hmmm, something like a **[UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller)** ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg no i just want to jump to gallery

Answer (score 1):

Apple do not allow you to move to Gallery through App. Hence you can open gallery for picking video & photos etc. You just can do like this if you want to pick from gallery :

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

 UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];

 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

Sets the file types you want to get on the property of the PickerViewControllerObject "mediaTypes" and you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer NO.

You can not open photos app using URL because Photos app does not register and URL schema.

[About Apple URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

`photos-redirect://` is the URL Scheme for Photo App. However, it is undocumented, thus you shouldn't use it.

Comment: quoted “As a result, this document does not describe all URL schemes supported on different Apple platforms.”